# gitlab-runner inside of docker image

Tags: windows, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I setup a windows docker image and started it on my Windows 10 machine.
In the running docker image registered the gitlab runner at my gitlab server.
The problem is that the gitlab server sees the ip address of the host Windows machine and as a result things it is online.

Is there anyway to run a build runner in an interactive docker image?

Here is my dockerfile

```
# escape=`

FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

RUN @"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"

# wait for vs_installer.exe, vs_installerservice.exe
# or vs_installershell.exe because choco doesn't
RUN powershell -NoProfile -InputFormat None -Command `
    choco install git 7zip -y; `
    choco install visualcpp-build-tools `
            -y; `
    Write-Host 'Waiting for Visual C++ Build Tools to finish'; `
    Wait-Process -Name vs_installer

#WORKDIR C:\build
#CMD powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command .\release.ps1

COPY entrypoint.bat entrypoint.bat

# Install Chocolatey
#RUN powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET #"PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"    

# Register the GitLab Runner
COPY gitlab-runner-windows-amd64.exe /gitlab/gitlab-runner.exe
RUN /gitlab/gitlab-runner.exe install

SHELL ["cmd.exe", "/s", "/c", "C:\\entrypoint.bat"]

WORKDIR /code

ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\entrypoint.bat"]
CMD ["cmd"]

EXPOSE 443
```

and my entrypoint.bat file

```
@echo off
pushd C:
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
REM call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools\vcbuildtools.bat"
popd
%*
```

Here is how I build it

```
docker build -t windows .
```

Here is how I run it

```
docker run -it windows cmd
```

Here is how I register the gitlab runner

```
C:\gitlab>gitlab-runner register --non-interactive --name "Windows docker builder" --url "https://gitlabserver/" --registration-token TOKEN --tag-list windows --executor shell
Registering runner... succeeded                     runner=XXX
Runner registered successfully. Feel free to start it, but if it's running already the config should be automatically reloaded!
```

On the GitLab Server I can see it is register but to it shows the ip address of the Windows 10 host machine not the ip address inside of docker.
[image]